# Cookie is still present after expiration date

Tags: angularjs, cookies

So I'm trying to use the ngCookie ($cookies) to set a boolean in AngularJs.
As you can see in the example below, the "someFlag" should only be true, if the cookie is still present. The cookie expiration is set to 30 seconds, but even after 30 seconds, the "someFlag" is still true.

So how do I manage to find out wether the cookie is expired or not?

```
var peekerHideCookie = $cookies.get('peekerHideCookie');
console.log(peekerHideCookie);
if (peekerHideCookie == 'true'){
    $scope.someFlag = true;
}

$scope.test = function () {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getSeconds() + 30);
    $cookies.put('peekerHideCookie', 'true', {expires: d});
    $scope.someFlag = true;
}
```

Comment: try this , d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 30);

Comment: Oh my.. Thanks a lot, such a silly mistake..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 30)` insetead of `d.setDate()`

```
 $scope.test = function () {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 30);
        $cookies.put('peekerHideCookie', 'true', {expires: d});
        $scope.someFlag = true;
    }
```

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d);
d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 30);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: I will, but I can't do it yet  :-)

Comment: Yes, but you can't accept an answer before 3-5 minutes has passed